# Brackets in a disjunction

Tags: logic, soft-question, intuition, propositional-calculus

How can one intuitively see that in a disjunction, putting brackets makes no difference? I mean for example: why is "At least one of the statements A, B, C, D, E, F, G is true" equivalent to "((A or B) or C) or (D or E) or (F or G)"?

Comment: That's because logical or is _associative_.

Comment: The bracketing can actually make a difference for some purposes.  Suppose we have a formula with fifty billion of fifty trillion or five million billion undecillion variables.  If we bracket it as follows: (A or (B or ... , then if A is true, we can determine the whole formula as true.  But, if we bracket it as (((((... A or B) or C) or ..., then it can take much longer for the truth value of the formula to get determined and possibly determining the truth value of the formula takes too long.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see that $\bbox[pink, 1pt]{(A\text{ or } B)\text{ or }C}$ is equivalent to $\bbox[pink, 1pt]{A\text{ or } (B\text{ or }C)}$ and therefore either can be written as $\bbox[pink, 2pt]{A\text{ or } B\text{ or }C}$ without ambiguity?

> Assume the truth of $\bbox[pink, 1pt]{(A\text{ or } B)\text{ or }C}$.   This means that either $\bbox[pink, 2pt]{A\text{ or } B}$ or $\bbox[pink, 2pt]{C}$ is true.   This means at least one of $\bbox[pink, 2pt]{A}$, $\bbox[pink, 2pt]{B}$, or $\bbox[pink, 2pt]{C}$ is true.   This in turn means either $\bbox[pink, 2pt]{A}$ or $\bbox[pink, 2pt]{B\text{ or }C}$ is true.   Hence $\bbox[pink, 1pt]{A\text{ or }(B\text{ or }C)}$ is true.   Also *vice versa*.   Therefore the original, middle, and final statements are equivalent.

$$\bbox[pink, 1pt]{(A\text{ or } B)\text{ or }C} \equiv\bbox[pink, 2pt]{A\text{ or } B\text{ or }C} \equiv \bbox[pink, 1pt]{A\text{ or } (B\text{ or }C)}$$

All mean, "At least one of $\bbox[pink, 2pt]{A}, \bbox[pink, 2pt]{B},\bbox[pink, 2pt]{C}$ is true."

Does your intuition now agree that this principle of *associativity* can be extended to a disjunctive series of any length, such as:

$$\bbox[pink, 1pt]{(A\text{ or } B)\text{ or }(C\text{ or }D)\text{ or }(E\text{ or }F)}$$

...means: $\text{At least one of }\bbox[pink, 2pt]{A}, \bbox[pink, 2pt]{B},\bbox[pink, 2pt]{C},\bbox[pink, 2pt]{D},\bbox[pink, 2pt]{E},\text{ or }\bbox[pink, 2pt]{F}\text{ is true.}$

Comment: In "(A or B) or C" and in "A or (B or C)" it seems reasonable to interpret 'or' as binary.  But, in "A or B or C" it seems reasonable to interpret 'or' as ternary.  (A or B) or C indicates that (A or B) gets computed first, and then whatever that computes to gets computed with C.  A or B or C indicates that the entire computation happens in a single step.  So, no, I'm not so sure you've written the same things, even though they end up as truth-functionally equivalent.